# CFile write function

Tags: c++, mfc, cfiledialog, cfile

I have got a question about the MFC CFile write function. 
I am learning about MFC application and stuck at this Save As and write function.
When I click the TestButton, a save as dialog box would pop out prompting to save as txt file.

```
void CLearnDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest()
{
CString m_strPathName;
char* File;
TCHAR szFilters[] = 
    _T ("Text files (*.txt)¦*.txt¦All files (*.*)¦*.*¦¦");

CFileDialog dlg (FALSE, _T ("txt"), _T ("*.txt"),
    OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilters);

if (dlg.DoModal () == IDOK)
    m_strPathName = dlg.GetPathName();

CFile DataFile(m_strPathName, CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeCreate);

char buffer0[100] = "TEST0";
char buffer1[100] = "TEST1";
int GetLength;


for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    File = (("%S, %S\n\n"), buffer0, buffer1);
    GetLength = strlen(File);
    DataFile.Write(File, GetLength);
}
DataFile.Close();
MessageBox(_T("OK"));
}
```

Question is how do I write two buffer together into a single  `File` then write it into the `DataFile` and making a new line every time it write?
The output file is saved but only one buffer (TEST1) is saved twice without going to a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is something wrong with your code if your code is right , then your programming statement

```
File = (("%S, %S\n\n"), buffer0, buffer1);
```

Has only one meaning is that , create File character array first with buffer0 and replace it with buffer1 so finally you will get buffer1 as final File value.

About **\n** not working properly because it should be like, **\r\n**

So your final program may look like,

```
      // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CString m_strPathName;
    char* File;
    TCHAR szFilters[] = 
        _T ("Text files (*.txt)¦*.txt¦All files (*.*)¦*.*¦¦");

    CFileDialog dlg (FALSE, _T ("txt"), _T ("*.txt"),
        OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilters);

    if (dlg.DoModal () == IDOK)
        m_strPathName = dlg.GetPathName();

    CFile DataFile(m_strPathName, CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeCreate);

    char buffer0[100] = "TEST0";
    char buffer1[100] = "TEST1";
    int GetLength;

    File = new char[strlen(buffer0)+strlen(buffer1)+2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        strcpy(File,buffer0);
        strcat(File,buffer1);
        strcat(File,"\r\n");
        GetLength  = strlen(File);
        DataFile.Write(File, GetLength);
    }
    DataFile.Close();
    MessageBox(_T("OK"));

    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

**[EDIT]**

```
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CString m_strPathName;
    char* File;
    TCHAR szFilters[] = 
        _T ("Text files (*.txt)¦*.txt¦All files (*.*)¦*.*¦¦");

    CFileDialog dlg (FALSE, _T ("txt"), _T ("*.txt"),
        OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilters);

    if (dlg.DoModal () == IDOK)
        m_strPathName = dlg.GetPathName();

    CFile DataFile(m_strPathName, CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeCreate);

    char buffer0[100] = "TEST0";
    char buffer1[100] = "TEST1";
    int GetLength;

    File = new char[strlen(buffer0)+strlen(buffer1)+2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        double doublevalue;
        doublevalue = 1035.25414;
        sprintf(File,"%s,%s,%f\r\n", buffer0, buffer1,doublevalue);     //Dumping data string and double data saparated with comma
        GetLength = strlen(File);
        DataFile.Write(File, GetLength);
        sprintf(File,"%f>>>%s>>>%s\r\n", doublevalue,buffer1,buffer0);      //Dumping data double and string data saparated with >>
        GetLength = strlen(File);
        DataFile.Write(File, GetLength);
    }
    DataFile.Close();
    MessageBox(_T("OK"));
```

Comment: thank you, the code works. But if I want to add a third value into the `File = newchar .....` which is a `double` how do I do it? Like >> double, buffer0, buffer1 << Also how do I add a comma to separate the two buffer in the txt file? Like >> `TEST0, TEST1` << and so on.

Comment: @Ashton please see updated code after edit you will get what you required.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! But for double shouldn't I use `%lf`??

Comment: @Ashton depends on size and number of character you want. Means if you want big floating number then you should go through %lf else %f is much enough.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! Had completed this project earlier due to your help! Once again thank you!